# Alternative of push method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array called current markers, and each time a function is called the marker is added to the array

```
var currentMarkers=[];
          
        var mymarker=     new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates
          )
          .addTo(map); 
          
this.currentMarkers.push(mymarker); // pushing into the array
```

Is there any other method out there so that i can just update the values of the array instead of pushing new values into it? example

### just my concept

```
this.currentMarkers[0].update(mymarker);
```

Thank you so much for your time !

Comment: `this.currentMarkers[0] = mymarker`?

Comment: you should use `push` for adding items to an array. if you want to come up with something else, thats going to hurt maintainability - especially for others reading your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update a specific element of an array in JavaScript, just reference that element and assign it.

Example:

```
this.currentMarkers[0] = mymarker;
```